# Label not appearing in Swift table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, controller, storyboard

No data is appearing in my Swift table. I'm fairly new to Swift and not quite sure why this or what I might be missing. I followed the guide here for the most part with some differences:

[Apple Table Creation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html)

Here's the tableView definition:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "AccountTableViewCell"
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? AccountTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of AccountTableViewCell.")
        }

        let item = userDataSource[indexPath.row]
// Dummy values just to test this out
        cell.leftLabel.text = "test1";
        cell.rightLabel.text = "test2";

        return cell
    }

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->Int {
    return userDataSource.count;
// This should be an array value, but I have also tried passing a static int here as well to test
}
```

Here is my class definition with the implemented procotols:

```
class AccountViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
```

And here is my table cell definition:

```
class AccountTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var leftLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

I've got both rightLabel and leftLabel setup in the Storyboard.

I can go to the account page represented by this view controller and a table display does come up - it just has absolutely no data in it.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Did you set your view controller as the datasource for your tableview?  How/where do you load `userDataSource`?  Set breakpoints to see if `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt` are being called

Comment: AccountViewController is the class for the scene. Is that the same thing? I'll check on the breakpoints.

Comment: Did you register your reusable cells before using them?

Comment: @slickdaddy I am not quite sure what this means

Comment: When you add a table view to your view controller, you must register any reusable cells before dequeuing them. In your case: `tableView.register(AccountTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "AccountTableViewCell")`

Comment: Where would this go? in cellForRowAt?

Comment: Register the cell first

Comment: Put the code provided by @slickdaddy in your viewDidLoad() method

Comment: @NgugiNdung'u - that gives me an ambigious reference error

Comment: Is your table view a property of the view controller or did you declare `let tableView = UITableView()` inside a method?

Comment: @slickdaddy I did neither of those things. tableView: UITableView is being passed in as an argument of the tableView method in my AccountViewController class

Comment: Hold on.  First question: Have you set up your tableview using a storyboard or are you doing it programatically?  If you are using a storyboard then the cell registration is done for you.  You need to use the connections inspector to set your view controller as the table datasource object.

Comment: Storyboard. And it isn't enough that the table is inside the viewcontroller's scene?

Comment: No.  You need to set your view controller as the table view's data source.  In the connections inspector drag from the "data source" outlet to the view controller object. They didn't show this step in the Apple tutorial you referenced as they were using a UITableViewController which automatically makes this connection

Comment: @Paulw11 - I added an image to my question - could you point out if I did it correctly?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct.

Comment: Alright, let me do a build and check it out.

Comment: Ok, it seems to get to the tableView function now. Awesome. Throwing an error but it seems unrelated to this particular problem. So feel free to write an answer and get the points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not sufficient to simply add a `UITableView` to your view controller scene. You must set the tableview's `dataSource` property to your view controller instance in the Storyboard connections inspector for the tableview.

[image]